# Change position of columns in a dataframe by passing a (character) string of desired column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to change the position of columns in my dataframe as described [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Change-positions-of-columns-in-data-frame-td906511.html). But I do not know why this is not working. See below...

```
df1 <- structure(list(S01 = c(51L, 82L, 72L, 79L, 2L, 86L, 33L, 56L,3L, 35L), S02 = c(49L, 33L, 59L, 68L, 35L, 45L, 22L, 18L, 67L, 79L), S03 = c(109L, 103L, 112L, 100L, 102L, 110L, 106L, 105L,107L, 111L), S04 = c(136L, 160L, 46L, 298L, 133L, 96L, 224L, 82L, 238L, 283L), S05 = c(189L, 168L, 178L, 129L, 128L, 72L,77L, 171L, 4L, 65L)), .Names = c("S01", "S02", "S03", "S04", "S05"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
str(df1)  
correctCol <- c('S01','S03','S05','S02','S04') # this will be generated by a function in turn
df.correct <- subset[df1,select=correctCol]
```

It throws the following error:

```
Error in subset[df1, select = correctCol] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

**EDIT**

Yes, I was at mistake by not seeing it should have been `(` and not `[`

*This works*

```
df.correct <- subset(df1,select=correctCol)
```

Comment: `subset` is a function. You need to use parens rather than square-brackets.

Comment: You're mixing up answers from the thread. Re-read and look at `[`  and `(`.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question. I won't be offended and it will save time of others.

Comment: Whenever you see something about a closure in R it is very often (all the time?) referring to a function - you've tried to subset via `[` a function (`subset()`) which clearly doesn't make any sense and hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant

```
df.correct <- subset(df1, select = correctCol)
```

i.e. with `(` `)` not square brackets `[` and `]`.

Though do note you don't need `subset()` for this. Instead you can subset using `[` directly:

```
> subset(df1, select = correctCol) 
   S01 S03 S05 S02 S04
1   51 109 189  49 136
2   82 103 168  33 160
3   72 112 178  59  46
4   79 100 129  68 298
5    2 102 128  35 133
6   86 110  72  45  96
7   33 106  77  22 224
8   56 105 171  18  82
9    3 107   4  67 238
10  35 111  65  79 283
> df1[, correctCol]
   S01 S03 S05 S02 S04
1   51 109 189  49 136
2   82 103 168  33 160
3   72 112 178  59  46
4   79 100 129  68 298
5    2 102 128  35 133
6   86 110  72  45  96
7   33 106  77  22 224
8   56 105 171  18  82
9    3 107   4  67 238
10  35 111  65  79 283
```

Comment: The reason I mistakenly used `[` instead of `)` was that I was trying to do something like this but mixed up both

Comment: @GavinSimpson that was not me (in case you thought it was some sort of revenge)

Comment: @SimonO101 No, didn't think it was you, and your rep didn't change and someone did it to DWin too.